# Un-kick player from private ROBLOX server

Tags: roblox

I kicked someone from a private ROBLOX server as a joke, not knowing it wouldn’t let them rejoin. I wish to unkick that person from my private ROBLOX server, but I don’t know if it’s possible. If anyone knows a way to allow them to play on my server again, thanks.

Comment: It might help to add what exactly you did.  Was there a specific command you ran?

Answer (score 2):

Go to your game's Settings, then Permissions, the click on "Friends only". It should work then. If it doesn't, click "reset settings" then do it again.